# Truncate table with a stored procedure in Mariadb

Tags: sql, stored-procedures, mariadb, helper

I need to truncate a table with a stored procedure. Here is the code for the stored procedure:

```
DELIMITER //
CREATE PROCEDURE MA_ClearPenaltyExport

BEGIN

   TRUNCATE TABLE MA_STG_PenaltyExport;
    
END //
DELIMITER ;
```

but I'm getting an error as
#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'BEGIN

```
   TRUNCATE TABLE MA_STG_PenaltyExport;
    
END' at line 3
```

Comment: You are missing the parenthesis after the procedure name. Voting to close as "typo question".

Answer (score 1):

A its a single statement in the procedure the following also works:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE MA_ClearPenaltyExport()
TRUNCATE TABLE MA_STG_PenaltyExport;
```

Answer (score -1):

```
DELIMITER $$ 
CREATE OR REPLACE DEFINER=dbadmin@% PROCEDURE MA_ClearPenaltyExport( ) 
BEGIN 
TRUNCATE MA_STG_PenaltyExport; 
END$$
 DELIMITER ;
```

Comment: Thank you for contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This may be a correct answer, but it’d be really useful to provide additional explanation of your code so developers can understand your reasoning. This is especially useful for new developers who aren’t as familiar with the syntax or struggling to understand the concepts. **Would you kindly [edit] your answer to include additional details for the benefit of the community?**